# Enabling Use Secure URLs in Admin, magento not redirecting properly

Tags: magento, redirect, ssl

I have installed ssl in local PC and working correctly. Front end is using https and all good. But when I enable  Use Secure URLs in Admin; I cannot access the backend.

Its trying to redirect and ending up with `The page isn't redirecting properly` message in firefox.

Anybody know secure URLS in admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

Go to system > configuration > web . click on cookie session timeout tab. make sure the cookie path and cookie domain fields are empty for all store views also.

Answer (score 0):

Did you possibly made any changes in Cookie Path or Cookie Domain? If yes go to Stores > Configuration > General > Web > Default Cookie Settings and leave these fields blank.